# View HDMI output on Android Phone

Tags: usb, hdmi

I have a raspberry pi: it is normally run 'headless' (sans monitor).   I would like to be able to connect the video output on a Samsung Galaxy Phone.  For this exercise, the solution must use a wired connection (HDMI, USB) and not rely on a network connection (SSH / VNC or similar).

My Google search brings up articles of how to cast video from the Android device through HDMI.  I would like to wire and direct HDMI into the Android device's display.

## Questions:

Assuming there is a cable that can bridge HDMI into the Android device: does Android support wired HDMI capability?  What is the nomenclature for the capability?

Bonus: can the same thing be done from the raspberry pi's USB port?  That is, direct the video out through a USB port, through a USB cable and into the Android device for display?

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming there is a cable that can bridge HDMI into the Android device: does Android support wired HDMI capability? What is the nomenclature for the capability?

Nothing in the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd) indicates that such a feature is supported by Android.

Consider that HDMI inputs on a PC is usually done via specialized capture cards and that you are asking for physical input to device which normally operates on **battery**. Remember that any hardware that isn't being sold/used as a 'feature' is a waste of space and power on a phone.

> Bonus: can the same thing be done from the raspberry pi's USB port? That is, direct the video out through a USB port, through a USB cable and into the Android device for display?

You would need VNC but this thread indicates that it is possible over USB:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=105336